# How to add and exclude where() clause in laravel query builder

Tags: laravel

How to add and exclude where()  clause in laravel query builder so that in one case it will  be added in other one no

```
$orders =  DB::table('orders')->select(
'orders.id as id',
'orders.created_at as created',
    'u.email as email',
    'ud.id as data_id',
    'ud.firstName as firstName',
    'ud.lastName as lastName',
    'ud.phone as phone',
    's.name as service',
    's.id as service_id',
    'pt.id as payment_type_id',
    'pt.name as payment_name')
    ->join('users as u', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->join('user_data as ud', 'u.id', '=' ,'ud.user_id')
    ->join('payment_types as pt', 'orders.payment_type_id', '=', 'pt.id')
    ->join('services as s', 'orders.service_id', '=', 's.id')
    ->where('u.id', $user->id)->orderBy($sortBy, $type)->get();
```

I want to do this

```
$order = DB::table()....
if(true){
  $order->where('id', '=', 1);
}
$order->orderBy('fieldname', 'asc')->get();
```

But the example above return no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For conditional clauses you can make use of [`when()`](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#conditional-clauses).

```
$order = DB::table()
       ->yourQuery(...)
       ->when($var, function ($query, $var) {      // <----
           return $query->where('id', '=', 1);     // <----
       }                                           // <----
       ->orderBy('fieldname', 'asc')
       ->get();
```

You can read more about this in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#conditional-clauses):

> #### Conditional Queries
>
> Sometimes you may want clauses to apply to a query only when something
>   else is true. For instance you may only want to apply a `where`
>   statement if a given input value is present on the incoming request.
>   You may accomplish this using the `when` method:
>
> ```
> $role = $request->input('role');
>
> $users = DB::table('users')
>             ->when($role, function ($query, $role) {
>                 return $query->where('role_id', $role);
>             })
>             ->get();
> ```
>
> The `when` method only executes the given Closure when the first
>   parameter is `true`. If the first parameter is `false`, the Closure will
>   not be executed.
>
> ...